# НЕ или НИ? И нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, не-или-ни

*Какое счастье осознать однажды,

воскреснув **ни** единожды, **ни** дважды,

что ты — неисчерпаем для любви,

а мир так щедр на радостей огни!*

*И хочется напиться добрым светом...

И хочется поверить — всё не зря,

укутываясь чаем, книгой, пледом,**(?)**

под тихое мурррчанье N-тября...*
[Удри Будрайджи](https://www.stihi.ru/2015/01/21/11279)

1. **НЕ** или **НИ** нужно написать в сочетаниях *ни единожды*, *ни дважды*?
   (Мне кажется, что правильно **не**.)
2. Нужна ли запятая после "пледом"?
   (Мне она видится лишней.)

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, **не единожды, не дважды**. Это по смыслу понятно, ведь автор говорит именно о многократных воскрешениях, а не об их полном отсутствии.

Запятую я тоже считаю лишней.

Answer (score 1):

1. Частица **ни** во внешне похожих выражениях используется для усиления *предшествующего **отрицания*** (ср. ***не*** воскресал он ни единожды, ни дважды, **не** ощутив ни голода, ни жажды), которого здесь **нет**, в простом же перечислении того "*как и как ещё не было*" (здесь: воскрес больше двух раз, поскольку один или два раза отпадает, как "не то и не это") должно быть "**не**".
2. C пунктуацией во втором фрагменте не всё в порядке. Помимо *лишней* запятой, надо бы пунктуационно "извиниться" за смысловой разрыв между деепричастным оборотом и глаголом. Причина и следствие упомянуты в обратной последовательности: в процессе создания личного комфорта (укутываясь...) лирический герой хочет (благодаря этому комфорту) улучить момент успокоения и поверить в то, о чём говорит. Строго говоря, для согласования производителей действия глагола и деепричатия (безличное расходится с личным: "хотевшееся" не может "укутываться"), правильнее было бы сказать "у*кутываясь, я хочу поверить*"; в исходном же варианте вышел галлицизм (его можно списать на поэтическую вольность). Для исправления же пунктуации я бы предложил такой вариант:

> И хочется поверить: всё не зря! - укутываясь чаем, книгой, пледом под
>   тихое...